# SharpMap type conversion - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, sharpmap

I want to display a shapefile `.shp` in a SharpMap box, I wrote this code :

> ```
>     public partial class Details : UserControl
>     {
>         public Details()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>
>             SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer vlay = new SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("States");
>             string path = @"D:\Studies\file.shp";
>             SharpMap.Map myMap = new SharpMap.Map(new System.Drawing.Size(500, 250));
>             vlay=new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile(path);
>             MapBox.Map.Layers.Add(vlay);
>             MapBox.Map.ZoomToExtents();
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

it didn' run and it shows :

`SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile` can be converted to `SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer`

What should I do ?

Comment: Try `vlay.Datasource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile(path);` instead of `vlay = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile(path);`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign vlay.DataSource, Like Clemens says:

```
 SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer vlay = new SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("States");
 string path = @"D:\Studies\file.shp";
 vlay.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile(path);
 MapBox.Map.Layers.Add(vlay);
 MapBox.Map.ZoomToExtents();
 MapBox.Refresh();
```

Comment: thanks
but  `MapBox.Map` is underlined in `MapBox.Map.Layers.Add(vlay);
 MapBox.Map.ZoomToExtents();`

Comment: Did you create an instance of MapBox. see: https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SharpMap%20Tutorial